# Effectively dismiss and dispose Popup component in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to effectively dispose and dismiss Popup widget in Android Jetpack Compose through an event? Making the Popup invisible by a boolean flag throws a warning of improper dismissal.

```
Input channel object '5668e46 Pop-Up Window (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
```

```
if (showOverlay) {
            println(buttonPosition)
           val popup  = Popup(
             
                onDismissRequest = {
                    showOverlay = false
                },

                offset = IntOffset(
                    LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp, buttonPosition.y.toInt() + 48
                )
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.LightGray.copy(alpha = 0.7F))
                        .padding(16.dp)


                ) {
                  // Content
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason of the warning you getting that is because the Popup get disposed without the process of getting through necessary clean up,To dismiss the Popup correctly, you need to use state that is remembered across recompositions. Here's how implemented sate in jetpack compose :

```
var showOverlayState by remember { //make sure to use by delegate 
   mutableStateOf(false)
}
```

after creating the state :

```
if (showOverlay) {
    Popup(onDismissRequest = { showOverlay = false }) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.LightGray.copy(alpha = 0.7F))
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            // Content
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sure that I am using a remembered flag and still shows the warning.

Comment: provide more context about your code ?

Comment: Well, I am turning the showOverlay boolean to true upon Long Press and removing on onLongPressed end event

Comment: i mean by that are you using the Boolean state somewhere else in your code?